# Convert JSON Object as a Flat Obejct with Key value pair

Tags: java, json

I am getting a JSON object which looks like:

```
{
    "id": "1",
    "name": "Hw",
    "price": {
        "value": "10"
    },
    {
        "items": [{
            "id": "1"
        }]
    }
}
```

I want to represent this as flat map, but I want to represent the array of items as a list.

My output should look like:

```
{
"id": "1",
"name":"Hw",
"price":"10",
"items": ["1"]
}
```

Can anybody suggest me how I can achieve this? I tried this approach:

[How to deserialize JSON into flat, Map-like structure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20355261/how-to-deserialize-json-into-flat-map-like-structure)

Output from the above tried link:

```
{
"id": "1",
"name":"Hw",
"price.value":"10",
"items[0].id": "1"
}
```

But it is representing the arrays values as `array[0]`, `array[1]` which I don't need. I need this array as a list.

Comment: Your JSON input is not a valid JSON.

Answer (score 0):

The JSON you've given is not valid. I assume it's:

```
{
    "id": "1",
    "name": "Hw",
    "price": {
        "value": "10"
    },
    "items": [{
        "id": "1"
    }]
}
```

There cannot be a generic solution to what you're asking. But for this particular JSON, this will do(using [json-simple](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.googlecode.json-simple/json-simple/1.1.1)):

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public Map<String, String> transform(String inputJSON) throws ParseException {
    Map<String, String> result = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    JSONObject inputJSONObj = (JSONObject) new JSONParser().parse(inputJSON);
    String id = inputJSONObj.getOrDefault("id", "").toString();
    String name = inputJSONObj.getOrDefault("name", "").toString();
    String price = ((JSONObject) inputJSONObj.getOrDefault("price", new JSONObject())).getOrDefault("value", "")
            .toString();
    JSONArray itemsArray = (JSONArray) inputJSONObj.getOrDefault("items", new JSONArray());
    int n = itemsArray.size();
    String[] itemIDs = new String[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        JSONObject itemObj = (JSONObject) itemsArray.get(i);
        String itemId = itemObj.getOrDefault("id", "").toString();
        itemIDs[i] = itemId;
    }
    result.put("id", id);
    result.put("name", name);
    result.put("price", price);
    result.put("items", Arrays.toString(itemIDs));
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An approach for you with [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson). This do exactly what you want " represent this as flat map, but I want to represent the array of items as a list"

```
public class ParseJson1 {
    public static void main (String[] args){
        Type type = new TypeToken<HashMap<String, Object>>() {
        }.getType();
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String json = "{\n" +
                "           \"id\": \"1\",\n" +
                "           \"name\": \"Hw\", \n" +
                "           \"price\": {\n" +
                "               \"value\": \"10\"\n" +
                "           },\n" +
                "           \"items\": [{\n" +
                "               \"id\": \"1\"\n" +
                "           }]\n" +
                "      }\n";
        HashMap<String, Object> map = gson.fromJson(json, type);
        Object val = null;
        for(String key : map.keySet()){
            val = map.get(key);
            if(val instanceof List){
                for(Object s : (List)val){
                    System.out.println(key + ":" + s);
                }
            } else 
            System.out.println(key + ":" + map.get(key));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to convert your String in Map collection `Map<String, String>` which will help you to convert your `Map` Array to JSON format.

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
Map<String, String> mapObject = new HashMap<String, String>();
mapObject.put("id", "1");
mapObject.put("name", "VBage");
mapObject.put("mobile", "654321");

jsonObject.put("myJSON", mapObject);
System.out.println(jsonObject.toString());
```

Answer (score -1):

First, the JSON does not seems to have a correct format. Do you mean this?

```
{
    "id": "1",
    "name": "Hw",
    "price": {
        "value": "10"
    },
    "items": [{
        "id": "1"
    }]
}
```

In addition, since you were attaching the link of ([How to deserialize JSON into flat, Map-like structure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20355261/how-to-deserialize-json-into-flat-map-like-structure)), I assume you wants to flatten the JSON in the same manner, in which the result should be

```
{
   id=1,
   name=Hw,
   price.value=10,
   items[0]=1,
}
```

Also, if you just want the item to return a list of id (i.e. "items": ["1"]), then it is more logical to get a JSON of

```
{
    "id": "1",
    "name": "Hw",
    "price": {
        "value": "10"
    },
    "items": [ "1" ] // instead of "items": [{"id": "1"}]

}
```

The link that you have attached ([How to deserialize JSON into flat, Map-like structure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20355261/how-to-deserialize-json-into-flat-map-like-structure)) provides a general solution without any customization. It shouldn't know that "id" is the value you want to append on items.

Therefore, my **first suggestion is to change the JSON** to be  `"items": [ "1" ]`

If for any reasons the JSON cannot be changed, then you will need to do some **customization**, which will be like this:

```
import org.codehaus.jackson.*;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Map;

import org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper;
import org.codehaus.jackson.node.ArrayNode;
import org.codehaus.jackson.node.ObjectNode;
import org.codehaus.jackson.node.ValueNode;
import org.junit.Test;

public class Main {
    String json = "{\n" +
            "           \"id\": \"1\",\n" +
            "           \"name\": \"Hw\", \n" +
            "           \"price\": {\n" +
            "               \"value\": \"10\"\n" +
            "           },\n" +
            "           \"items\": [{\n" +
            "               \"id\": \"1\"\n" +
            "           }]\n" +
            "      }\n";

    @Test
    public void testCreatingKeyValues() {
        Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        try {
            addKeys("", new ObjectMapper().readTree(json), map);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println(map);
    }

    private void addKeys(String currentPath, JsonNode jsonNode, Map<String, String> map) {
        if (jsonNode.isObject()) {
            ObjectNode objectNode = (ObjectNode) jsonNode;
            Iterator<Map.Entry<String, JsonNode>> iter = objectNode.getFields();
            String pathPrefix = currentPath.isEmpty() ? "" : currentPath + ".";

            while (iter.hasNext()) {
                Map.Entry<String, JsonNode> entry = iter.next();
                // Customization here
                if (entry.getKey().equals("items")) {
                    ArrayNode arrayNode = (ArrayNode) entry.getValue();
                    for (int i = 0; i < arrayNode.size(); i++) {
                        addKeys(currentPath + entry.getKey() + "[" + i + "]", arrayNode.get(i).get("id"), map);
                    }
                } else {
                    addKeys(pathPrefix + entry.getKey(), entry.getValue(), map);
                }
            }
        } else if (jsonNode.isArray()) {
            ArrayNode arrayNode = (ArrayNode) jsonNode;
            for (int i = 0; i < arrayNode.size(); i++) {
                addKeys(currentPath + "[" + i + "]", arrayNode.get(i), map);
            }
        } else if (jsonNode.isValueNode()) {
            ValueNode valueNode = (ValueNode) jsonNode;
            map.put(currentPath, valueNode.asText());
        }
    }
}
```

Try understanding the format that you need, and then study the above code. It should give you the answer.